# How to make what is in a class public?

Tags: java, string, class

I have created my first class, which contributes to the code I've written for a GUI. However after any action performed buttons, the strings do not exist and are always underlined red, what do you suggest to solve this problem? In other words I need the entire program able to recognize these two strings. ADDED: I pretty much just need that values to be recognized for my binary search.

```
public class myFirstClass {

      String refNum, title;

        myFirstClass (String _refNum, String _title) {
            refNum= _refNum;
            title = _title;
        }
}

public static Boolean binarySearch(String [ ] A, int left, int right, String V){
         int middle;
         refNum++; //this is underlined red which is a problem
         if (left > right) {
             return false;
         }

         middle = (left + right)/2; //everything below is fine...
         int compare = V.compareTo(A[middle]);
         if (compare == 0) {
             return true;
         }
         if (compare < 0) {
             return binarySearch(A, left, middle-1, V);
         } else {
             return binarySearch(A, middle + 1, right, V);
         }
     }
```

Comment: What? Underlined where? In the IDE? In the GUI application you are writing?

Comment: You can use the `public` keyword. But show us some code for those *"action performed buttons"*, you may be needing a `final` qualifier somewhere also.

Comment: There's no context to the question.  How are you accessing the `string1` and `string2`?

Comment: Basically, your question makes no sense.

Comment: How about making those strings public?

Comment: Hmm, I guess my communication needs a little work...

Comment: Please work on the communication soon, before your question gets closed. Edit your question from their point of view, the point of view of someone who has no knowledge of your program or your problem, thinking "what would they need to know".

Comment: And no, don't make your fields public, despite what @Rogue recommends.

Comment: method is static, those fields are instance fields

Comment: @Sotirios Dekimanolis As much as I would love to be able to completely understand what you just commented...I don't. May you please clarify a bit more?

Comment: what are you trying to do with `string1++`. (string1 is a string and `++` is not defined on strings) This is a syntax error which is why it is probably underlined in red.

Comment: There is a lot wrong, take a basic java tutorial before you continue.

Comment: @FDinoff Eventually (though not added) string1 would a value(s) for as a reference for the binary to use to output 'true' or some anwser...and this isn't make much sense is it?

Comment: @user2407152 can you give better names to string1 and string2? That might help in understanding what you are trying to do.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels was more a statement of curiosity than of a solution :P

Answer (score 0):

You need to place `binarySearch()` inside the class. It is currently outside of `myFirstClass` which is why you are getting string1 is undefined.

```
public class myFirstClass {

      String string1, string2;

        myFirstClass (String _string1, String _string2) {
            string1= _string1;
            string2= _string2;
        }

      // Place binarySearch here
}
      // Not out here
```

Also inside binarySearch() `string1++` is a syntax error. However I am not sure how to fix this as I do not know what you are trying to accomplish.

**Edit:** string1 was renamed to refNum

So at this point refNum should just be converted to an integer since that what is looks like you are doing. You could do this with `num = Integer.parseInt(refNum);` where num is a variable inside of `myFirstClass`

So later on you could do `num++`

Comment: See I had originally thought placing the binarySearch where you just suggested, however 'Public Static Boolean bina...etc.' line was underlined an ugly shade of red and still is when I place it there now. So I assumed it belonged outside where only one word (refNum) was underlined...

Comment: It should be inside the class definition as you are making it a static method of the class also are there words if you mouse over the underlined stuff?

Comment: @user2407152 You're doing everything really wrong. Try to figure out why the underline is occurring, not just moving code around to see how to make the lines go away.